# Spring call EJB for Transaction

Tags: spring

Would like to confirm whether I can configure JtaTransactionManager with UserTransaction property for Spring bean with @Transactional annotation to call Container managed transaction bean in Application Server to update second database?  Appreciate you advice.

If i have seperate Spring bean with @transaction annotation need to call existing CMT bean to update same database which is 1 datasource only, can i reuse the same JtaTransactionManager or do i need to create single datasource TransactionManager to update 1 database?   Is that using DataSourceTransactionManager to update for 1 database only ?
Thanks in advance,  Leanne